# Method.invoke throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

Tags: java

```
public class ReflectionTest {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException  {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ReflectionTest t = new ReflectionTest();
            Method method[]= t.getClass().getMethods();
            System.out.println(method.length);
            for(int i=0;i<=method.length;i++){
                method[i].invoke(t);
            }
        }
            public void abc(){
                System.out.println("abc");
            }
            public void xyz(){
                System.out.println("XYZ");
            }
    }
```

Result shows:

```
abc
xyz
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.selenium.test.ReflectionTest.main(ReflectionTest.java:21)
```

Please help me how to handle this

Comment: Your upper limit of the for loop is too big, it should be more like i<method.length.

Answer (score 3):

The error is because along with abc() and xyz(), you have lot of other methods present.

```
equals
hashCode
toString
abc
xyz
getClass
notify
notifyAll
wait
```

You can use below logic if you want to run your methods

```
for(int i=0;i<method.length;i++){

    if(method[i].getName().equals("abc") || method[i].getName().equals("xyz"))
    {
        method[i].invoke(t);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you need to skip invoking `main` (since it requires a `String[] args`) and other method(s) of `Object`, that is

```
ReflectionTest t = new ReflectionTest();
Method method[] = t.getClass().getMethods();
System.out.println(method.length);
for (int i = 0; i < method.length; i++) {
  if (method[i].getName().equals("abc") || method[i].getName().equals("xyz")) {
    try {
      method[i].invoke(t, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

seems to work correctly here.

Comment: But still i am getting the same result after modifying using the above.

Comment: @user1948008 Edited. There are other methods that you don't want to invoke involved. Just test that it is a method you do want.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in

```
for(int i=0;i<=method.length;i++){
            method[i].invoke(t);
}
```

you iterate until `i` has the same value like method.length. 
Because an array start with 0 and the method.length count from 1.

You have to iterate until `i<method.length` OR `i<=method.length-1`

For example.

method[] has one item.

```
method[0] <- first and only item
method.length <- will return 1 becuase there is only one item.
```

You can say:

```
method[method.length-1] <- this will be the last item.
```

Answer (score 0):

Think again what are you doing. 
You iterate over all public methods available in your class (including methods declared in super class) and try to invoke without arguments, i.e. assume that all methods do not accept any argument that is definitely wrong. For example `equals(Object)` or `wait(long)` inherited from `java.lang.Object` require one argument.

EDIT

The same is about your own method `main(String[])`.

Occasionally `getMethods()` returns first 2 methods that do not require arguments: `abc()` and `xyz()` that are invoked successfully. Then the turn of `main()` arrives and you fail. But even if you add some `if()` statement to ignore `main`  you will fail on one of methods inherited from `Object` that I have already mentioned.

If you want to try only methods declared in your class use `getDeclaredMethods()` instead of `getMethods()`.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when you try to call a method that needs parameters without supplying any.

For a general solution you might want to test this:

```
if (method[i].getParameterTypes().length ==0)
{
   method[i].invoke(t);
}
```

This tests if the method has parameters and skips it

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes%28%29)